# "adjacent_find could not be resolved" error

Tags: c++11

I'm trying to use adjacent_find in C++ as part of a maximum algorithm, but I'm not exactly succeeding.  It worked in Xcode, mainly because it uses a different compiler.  Now, I'm in Eclipse on a cygwin compiler, and it's not working.  I already put the "-std=c++11" flag.  Help?

This is the code I used:

```
if (adjacent_find(list.begin(), list.end(), not_equal_to<int>()) == list.end())
        return -1; // all elements are equal
```

I can't check which version of Xcode I used because the computer is destroyed... sry.  But I'm using Eclipse Cpp Neon version 4.6.2.

Comment: You need to state which version of Xcode you were using, where are you trying to compile it now, on which compiler and version and possibly show some code.

Comment: Is that OK @Jack?